# BERTopic document visualization same color for a list of topics

Tags: python, word-embedding, topic-modeling

I have used BERTopic to make embeddings and get topics. I now want to visualize documents. I have partitioned by topics into three categories, A, B, C. I'd like to plot topics of each category in the same color. Example below:

```
A = [1,2,3]
C = [4, 5, 6]
B = [7, 8, 9]
reduced_embeddings = UMAP(n_neighbors=10, n_components=2, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine').fit_transform(embedding_mini)

bertopic_model_mini.visualize_documents(docs, topics=A, reduced_embeddings=reduced_embeddings, \
                                            hide_annotations=False, sample=0.1)
```

Is it possible to color all documents topics, 1,2,3 in the same color?